# How to compare only certain cells from a rows stored in an array

Tags: php, html, arrays, rows, cells

Got a strange situation and I don't know how to figure it out. Let's see if you can give me a hint!

I've built an array with rows in his content like this and want to delete duplicates:

**echo $nodup_filter[1];**

```
<tr>
<td>29/06/2015</td>
<td>09:00</td>
<td>29/06/2015</td>
<td>12:00</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>code 1</td>
<td>1007 Additional information 5</td>
<td>109 Additional information 6</td>
<td>Additional information 7</td>
<td>Additional information 8</td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
```

**echo $nodup_filter[2];**

```
<tr>
<td>12/02/2015</td>
<td>16:00</td>
<td>14/04/2015</td>
<td>18:00</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>Code 2</td>
<td>Additional information 1</td>
<td>Additional information 2</td>
<td>Additional information 3</td>
<td>Additional information 4</td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
```

**echo $nodup_filter[3];**

```
 <tr>
<td>29/06/2015</td>
<td>09:00</td>
<td>29/06/2015</td>
<td>12:00</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>code 1</td>
<td>1007 Additional information 5</td>
<td>109 Additional information 6</td>
<td>Additional information 7</td>
<td>Additional information 8</td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
```

And so on and so forth...

What I want is to compare the entire array, but **only from the sixth cell** to the end of every array position.

I want to compare this:

```
<td>code 1</td>
<td>1007 Additional information 5</td>
<td>109 Additional information 6</td>
<td>Additional information 7</td>
<td>Additional information 8</td>
<td> </td>
```

With this:

```
<td>Code 2</td>
<td>Additional information 1</td>
<td>Additional information 2</td>
<td>Additional information 3</td>
<td>Additional information 4</td>
<td> </td>
```

And with this:

```
<td>code 1</td>
<td>1007 Additional information 5</td>
<td>109 Additional information 6</td>
<td>Additional information 7</td>
<td>Additional information 8</td>
<td> </td>
```

And if there is a match, delete the duplicate array position. As you can see the $nodup_filter[1]; and $nodup_filter[3]; got the same information from his sixth cell to the end of the row, so one of them ($nodup_filter[1] or $nodup_filter[3]) need to be deleted. And then, continue compairing with the next array position..

Beforehand, thanks a lot for your help and time.

Comment: show us the php `array` content, you have only shared `html` table

Comment: Are `$nodup_filter` elements like strings, or is every element composed of other elements (i.e. one string for every cell)?

Comment: @Giorgio Thanks a lot for your reply, $nodup_filter is only formed by one string line:

<tr><td>29/06/2015</td><td>09:00</td><td>29/06/2015</td><td>12:00</td><td>3</td><td>code 1</td><td>1007 Additional Information 5</td><td>109 Additional information 6</td><td>Additional information 7</td><td>Additional information 8</td><td> </td></tr>

Comment: @user3321425 Ok just give me some minutes to build an answer.

Comment: @Saqueib sorry, didn't read your question since now. The html above is the content of every "echo". i.e. every array position stores only a string (which is one entire row in the same line). Here's the line stored in $nodup_filter[1]:
<tr><td>29/06/2015</td><td>09:00</td><td>29/06/2015</td><td>12:00</td><td>3</td>‌​<td>code 1</td><td>1007 Additional Information 5</td><td>109 Additional information 6</td><td>Additional information 7</td><td>Additional information 8</td><td> </td></tr>

I'm trying to figure it out. I'll post the solution if I find a way :) Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have it in array you can loop and check the content of **only from the sixth cell** `text`, one way to doing this will be this

```
$unique_array = array();
foreach($data as $k=>$v) {
   // assuming $data[$k][6] sixth cell
   if( in_array($data[$k][6], $unique_array) ) { 
      //remove duplicate 
      unset($data[$k]);
   }else {
     //Push it to final array 
     array_push($unique_array, $v);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! well, I want to check the content from the sixth cell to the end. I'm trying to compare the content of 6-7-8-9-10-11 cells from $nodup_filter[]; to delete the entire array position it there is a position where 6-7-8-9-10-11 is exactly the same with another $nodup_filter[]; position . I'll try to figure it out with the help of your code.